# _Blank on links with JS on an Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm currently at work and either me and my boss did not manage to find what happend on my JS/Jquery function.

Assuming I have an Iframe within `id="iframematin"`, We managed to count every link on the iframe, but after emptying cache, nothing.

My goal there is to count every a on my iframe, before giving them `_blank` option.

Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Chargement des aperçus"
var id_news_matin = $("#apercu_matin").data('id-news');
/* $("#apercu-ajax-matin").load (
    "https://www.monfinancier.com/proxy-apercu-newsletter.php?id="+id_news_matin+"&edition=matin #tableau-principal", 
    function(){
        $("#apercu-ajax-matin").find('#tableau-principal').find(".table").css({"margin": "auto"});
        console.log("done");
    }
); */

$('#type_news').on('change', function(e)
{
    var type = $(this).val();

    $('#news1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#news2').css('display', 'none');
    $('#news3').css('display', 'none');
            $('#news4').css('display', 'none');

    $('#news' + type).css('display', '');
});

    console.log('nb ' + parent.getElementsByTagName('a').length);

    $('#iframematin').ready(function(){
        console.log("iframematin chargé");
        var a = $('#iframematin').contents().find("a");
        console.log("nombre de lien comptés " + a.length);

        a.each(function(){
            console.log("lien : " + $(this).attr("href"));

            $(this).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert($(this).attr('href'));
            });      
        });
    });
```

});

Comment: are your site and the iframe on the same domain?

Comment: yes they are on the same domain

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/f3z9ufdq/ - perhaps try .on("load") instead of .ready?

Comment: is this script at the bottom of the page or wrapped in a $(function() {}) ?

Comment: this is what i'm supposed to have, but this is not working for any reason holy fk

Comment: I'm editing the whole function

Comment: @mplungjan thank you a lot boy it works !